How do I collapse all functions/classes in Google Collab
Pressing Ctrl+Shift+A opens up the Chrome Search Manu,
Instead I can do Ctrl+A to select all within a cell
However when I press Ctrl + [ or Ctrl + ] it just shifts text left or right. It does not collapse anything
I cannot find a Collapse option in the View menu either
